# Go Template - Передача переменной javascript

Tags: javascript, golang, переменные, шаблоны

Как передать переменную javascript в роле аргумента для метода в go?

```
$(document).on("click", ".row", function() {
    id = $(this).find(".row_id").text();
    {{.GetClients $client_id}}
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Так не выйдет потому что клиентская и серверная часть работают отдельно. Можна через jQuery ajax() к примеру.